# arc4random non-modulo bias?

Tags: objective-c, arc4random

I am using `arc4random() %2` in my code. It is called by 3 classes upon initialization, which happens in quick succession. However, approximately 70% plus of the results are always either all 0 or all 1 (the distribution between the 2 sets of 000 or 111 seems average). I would have expected a fairly random distribution of 1 and 0 between the 3 classes. How can this be explained?

Comment: Could this be a seeding issue?

Comment: Are you creating one arc4random(), or multiple instances?  If multiple, are you seeding them independently?

Comment: @pjs it is not possible to directly seed arc4random

Comment: Do you have some code that demonstrates this?

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I cannot say this definitively, it does appear to be a seeding "issue". Calling arc4random() multiple times within milliseconds of each other will have a very high bias towards certain numbers. acr4random_uniform seems to solve this problem - seemingly it is seeded in a more "robust" manner

Answer (score -1):

Use `acr4random_unform(3)` to avoid **modulo bias**

Read This Article:- http://nshipster.com/random/

Comment: As was noted under the other answer which made the same suggestion _two days ago_, this isn't a case of modulo bias.